# Why do I get a NullPointerException when checking against non-null values?

Tags: java, generics, null, nullpointerexception

I have this constructor:

```
public class SentinelT<T> extends NodeT<T> {

    //constructs an empty Sentinel linked to no other Nodes
    public SentinelT() {
        super(null, null, null);
    this.prev = this;
    this.next = this;
    }
...
}
```

So whenever I try to change the values of this.prev or this.next, or I try to use boolean operators on those values, I get a NullPointerException. For example:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return this.prev == this && this.next == this;
}
```

throws a NullPointerException. I have a feeling I just don't understand something about super constructors or null values... Thanks for any help.

*Edit: added NodeT constructor, going to add the instantiation that throws the exception

```
//NodeT class for a doubly linked list of T
public class NodeT<T> {
    T data;
    NodeT<T> prev;
    NodeT<T> next;

    //constructs a Node object
    public NodeT(T data, NodeT<T> prev, NodeT<T> next) {
    this.data = data;
    this.prev = prev;
    this.next = next;
    }
```

*edit2: different class, assume that stringHeader is a field of the class that this takes place in
        SentinelT stringHeader = new SentinelT();

```
    public void testIsEmpty(Tester t) {
    initData();

    t.checkExpect(stringHeader.isEmpty(), true);
}
```

Comment: just realized my isEmpty() method is overly complex.. simplified it to "return this.prev == this && this.next == this;" obviously this doesn't change the error though

Comment: What does the NodeT constructor look like? And can you post an actual invocation that throws (e.g., a small `main` function or something)?

Comment: Stacktrace shows the line number of your NPE. Show us that line (and maybe some context).

Comment: Can the code in isEmpty() actually throw a NullPointerException? Or are you maybe simply calling isEmpty() on an object that is null?

Comment: perhaps it's an issue with this tester package that my professor has us use?

Comment: the line where the checkExpect method is called is where I'm getting a nullpointerexception

Comment: @BlakeMadden: then I assume `t` is `null`. try `System.out.println("t is null: " + (t == null));` between `initData()` and the `checkExpect()` call.

Comment: This code can only throw a `NullPointerException` if `t` is `null`, or if `initData` throws an NPE for some reason. Your constructor cannot throw a null pointer exception, nor can your `isEmpty` method.

Comment: t is not null. just tested it with the code above

Comment: @BlakeMadden: run the same statement with `stringHeader` instead of `t`.

Comment: stringHeader was null, in the initData method I accidentally left the type in front of all of the fields that I was assigning values to, so I had String abc; as a field for example, and then in initData, I had String abc = ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard for me to say for sure what is wrong without seeing more code, but you say that you are getting a "NullPointerException" when checking against non-null values.  Have you used a debugger, and put a breakpoint in isEmpty and proved that during the execution of isEmpty that this.prev and this.next are non-null? I would highly suggest using breakpoints to verify your assumptions about the values of these data members.

EDIT - upon seeing your edit: This is a prime example of why you must show more code than where you are giving your error.  There is often more to the story.  Debuggers are a coder's best friend.  Verify your assumptions in the debugger.

Comment: I'll see if I can figure out how to use a debugger from the command line. Not on my usual terminal so I haven't used one here before.

Comment: I highly recommend Eclipse, Netbeans, or IntelliJ IDEA.  They are three great IDEs (listed in my order of preference) that all have superb line by line debuggers.

Comment: I use emacs for editing, and I haven't gotten around to installing any IDEs on Ubuntu. Just got Ubuntu the other day.

Comment: Eclipse is probably your best bet if you are using Ubuntu.  I find it hard, personally, to write code in any language without some sort of debugger.  Maybe I'm just a man of convenience, but I long ago got sick of chasing my tail trying to figure out the answers to problems that are trivial if I can just see the values during runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `this` can't be `null` ever.  Therefore, either `prev` or `next` must be `null`.  Your constructor assigns `this` to both `prev` and `next`, so that can't be the reason one of them is `null`.  Therefore, there must be other code you're not showing that sets one (or both) of them to `null`.

**EDIT**

On second thought, just because a value is `null`, doesn't mean it'll throw NPE here.

**SECOND EDIT**

With `testIsEmpty` code being revealed, then either `t` or `stringHeader` must be `null`.

Comment: I'm not sure even that matters.  I can't see how isEmpty(), as written, can ever throw a NPE.

Comment: Good point, it must be something else.

Comment: Oh man now I need to go and remove all the `if (this != null)` checks from my code.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see this happening is if `stringHeader` or `t` is `null`...

(props to jlordo for `t`)...

Comment: or `t` could be `null`...

Comment: Good point... I'll add it!

Answer (score 0):

Lets be clear about this:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return this.prev == this && this.next == this;
}
```

That method CANNOT throw a `NullPointerException`.  None of the operations it performs can throw any exceptions:

- `this` cannot be `null` so, `this.prev` and `this.next` cannot thrown an NPE
- Using `==` to compare a reference with `null` (or any other reference) cannot throw an NPE.

So if you are getting an NPE, it is coming from somewhere else ... and you are misinterpreting the stack trace.

---

Second example:

```
t.checkExpect(stringHeader.isEmpty(), true);
```

In this example, there are a few ways that an NPE *could* be thrown.

- If `stringHeader` is `null` then `stringHeader.isEmpty()` will throw an NPE.
- If `t` is `null`, then an NPE will be thrown by the `t.checkExpect` call.

It also possible (in theory) that an NPE could be thrown within the `checkExpect` or `isEmpty` calls, but the stacktrace would provide evidence that that had happened.

---

Lessons to learn from this:

- Read the stack trace carefully, and learn to to interpret it correctly.
- Read the code that you have written.  Read it carefully.
- Make sure that you understand what Java constructs can and what cannot throw an NPE ... or other intrinsic exceptions.  (There are some subtleties in certain cases ... though not here.)
- Don't jump to conclusions that are not supported by the evidence.  'Cos you are likely waste lots of time by doing that ... if your "conclusion" turns out to be incorrect.
- If you can't figure it out, look for more evidence:

  - Use a debugger to set breakpoints, examine variables, single step the code, etcetera
  - Add logging or (temporary) trace-prints.
  - "Hand execute" in your head or on paper.
- If you are asking someone else for help, they will need to see **ALL** relevant code stack traces and other evidence so that they can reason it through themselves.  If you just provide your (possibly incorrect) interpretation of the evidence, you won't get useful help.
- Don't assume that the problem is in someone else's code: *"perhaps it's an issue with this tester package that my professor has us use?"* .... WRONG!